# Elasticsearch: Searching for fields with mapping not_analyzed get no hits

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mapping

I have elasticsearch running and do all my requests with nodejs.
I have the following mapping applied for my index "mastert4":

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "mastert4": {
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added exactly one document to the index which looks pretty much like this:

```
{
  "master": {
    "vi": "ff155d9696818dde0627e14c79ba5d344c3ef01d",
    "s": "Anne Will"
  }
}
```

Now doing any of the following search queries will not return any hits:

```
{
  "index": "mastert4",
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "match"/"term": {
            "s": "anne will"/"Anne Will"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

}

But the following query will return the exact document:

```
    {
      "index": "mastert4",
      "body": {
        "query": {
          "filtered": {
            "query": {
              "constant_score": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "missing": {
                      "field": "s"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And if I search for

```
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "s"
      }
    }
```

I will get no hits again.

When analyzing the field itsself I get:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Anne Will",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm really in a dead end here. Can someone tell me where I did wrong? Thx!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've enclosed the fields `s` and `vi` inside an outer field called `master` which is not declared in your mapping. That's the reason. If you query for `master.s`, you'll get results.

The second solution is to remove the enclosing `master` object in your document and that will work also:

```
{
    "vi": "ff155d9696818dde0627e14c79ba5d344c3ef01d",
    "s": "Anne Will"
}
```

Comment: So it's just the mapping that's wrong? 
Because a search in the same way for the field vi, works perfectly well? 
I'll definetly try a mapping for master.s in the same way.

Comment: Depends on how you created your mapping and indexed your documents, though judging by what you're showing in your question, I can definitely say that the mapping and the document are not in synch. What does `curl -XGET localhost:9200/mastert4/_mapping` get you?

Comment: I can't check the mapping right now, but that makes sense. Should be a good start! I'll try it asap

Comment: Have you been able to try this out?

Comment: Yes, checking the mapping helped out a lot! I found more than one mistake. It was a far more complex problem:
1) I set the wrong path and didn't consider the correct documentname.
2) the mapping itsself should've been: `{ properties: { master: { properties:{ "vi": ...` and so on.
Fixed that and it works fine now.